# The expression $i^{i^{i^2}}$ can be written $e^\alpha$ for some real number $\alpha \in [0, 2\pi)$. What is $α$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The expression $i^{i^{i^2}}$ can be written $e^\alpha$ for some real number $\alpha \in [0, 2\pi)$. What is $α$?

I am not sure what this is asking, could I get a hint on where to start?

Comment: Some parenthesis are missing, I think.

Comment: What would be your answer to 2^3^2? $64$ or $512$?

Comment: Interestingly, it's possible to [directly google for the answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=i%5Ei%5Ei%5E2&oq=i%5Ei%5Ei%5E2), or at least for *an answer*.

Comment: Do you mean, for example, $i^{i^{i^2}}$ (`i^{i^{i^2}}` between two dollar signs)? [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would disambiguate.

Comment: It would be i^(i^(i^2)), but how can I write it as a real number?

Comment: It is a convention that exponentiation is done from the right (or from above), hence $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$. This way we get the biggest possible number , if we have a power tower , which is the first step to get HUGE numbers (googology is dealing with those ridiculous large numbers).

Answer (score 2):

The calculation $i^{i^{i^2}}=i^{-i}=e^{-i(\pi i/2+2n\pi i)}=e^{2n\pi+\pi/2},\,n\in\Bbb Z$ [is multi-valued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_complex_bases), but for your purposes we take the $n=0$ branch.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that if there is no parentheses, you evaluate top down. So $2^{2^{2^2}}$ would equal $2^{16}$ rather than $256$. Thus, $i^{i^{i^2}} = i^{i^{-1}} = i^{-i} = (i^i)^{-1}$. Note that $e^{\pi i} = -1$, thus $e^{\pi i/2} = i. $ Thus, we get $(e^{\pi i/2})^i = i^i $ which becomes $e^{-\pi/2} = i^i$. We had this equation before $i^{i^{i^2}} = i^{i^{-1}} = i^{-i} = (i^i)^{-1}$, so now we can substitute in our value for $i^i$ to get $i^{i^{i^2}}   = (e^{-\pi/2})^{-1} = e^{\pi/2}$.